Lab] Cisco, ensuring traffic goes between a specific switch port and trunk port
I am not even sure how to search this.  I need gi2/12 to only be able to talk to 1 specific vm as it needs direct internet access. how does one protect vlanX from receiving any traffic on a vlan that is setup specifically to tie physical port gi2/12 to a specific vm through a trunk/lag port ? GI2/12 is connected directly to the isp modem.
due to circumstance I am currently unable to install another network card to allow a dedicated Ethernet port. the vm would be assigned a 72.x ip and be talking directly to the isp device. the vm would be on a trunk

Your question seems unclear. Is port Gi2/12 connected to the host hardware that runs the virtual machine? Or is Gi2/12 the port connected to the internet service?
The way I understand your question, it seems you want to actually just make sure that only that one VM has access to the internet uplink, is that right? If so, then simply make a VLAN for the internet service and only configure that one VM's virtual network interface to connect to that VLAN. Other VMs on the platform won't know that VLAN exists.

If you use LAG you can only indirectly control traffic distribution to a specific interface by altering the source/destination MAC/IP/L4 port - whatever your gear uses or is configured to use. That is an intricate business and often not possible due to the lack of control over the other traffic.
If you want a dedicated interface, don't aggregate with others. Instead, use a distinct VLAN or L3 port on the switch. Host/hypervisor configurations are off topic here.

I was coming from a view of  from gi2/12 that connects to the isp and goes to a vm through a trunk on a server. the server/vm security part was not under question.  The part i was confused by was if having a vlan X inter face or not mad a difference and if there was any thing else that would need to be implemented on the cisco to keep it from allowing access ivr or otherwise to the vlan.  I know there is acl.s that can be set per vlan to allow/disallow traffic between them or not.  I currently do not have a vlan X interface on that vlan.
